# Sending data over socket in Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, sockets, socket.io

I need to connect to a `socket` and send *credential* info in order to start receiving upcoming data over **RECEIVE_CRISIS**.

I'm using the library **Socket.IO** for Android code. It's really hard to debug since I got no Log from the connection, I don't know why and where it fails. I just never received anything from the server since I started working on the Android side. Is the `NSDictionary` equivalent to the `JSONObject` on Android? Is `sendEvent` equivalent to `send()` or `emit()` on Android? Do I need to send the JSON as an Object or an Array? Finally, how to I get the log error?

It's working on iOS part so I'm kinda lost..

This is the **iOS** code : (I modify the address for safe purpose):

```
NSDictionary *params=@{@"user":_username,@"orgid":_organizationId};
[_socketIO connectToHost:@"nodejs.myserver.com" onPort:3000 ];
   [_socketIO sendEvent:@"joinparty" withData:params];
```

This is the **Android** code :

```
private void connectAndListen(int username) throws Exception {
    socket = IO.socket("nodejs.myserver.com:3000");
    socket.connect();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("user", username);
    json.put("orgid", settings.getString("orgid", ""));

    Log.e(TAG, json.toString());

    socket.send("joinparty",json);
    socket.emit("joinparty", json);

    socket.on(RECEIVE_CRISIS, onCrisis);
}
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

```
private void connectAndListen(int id) throws Exception {
    IO.setDefaultSSLContext(SSLContext.getDefault());

    // Set default hostname
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
            return true;
        }
    };
    IO.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
    // set as an option
    options.sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    options.hostnameVerifier = hostnameVerifier;
    options.secure = true;
    socket = IO.socket("nodejs.myserver.com:3000", options);
    socket.connect();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("user", id);
    json.put("orgid", settings.getString("orgid", ""));

    Map<Object, Object> arrays = new HashMap<>();
    arrays.put("user", id);
    arrays.put("orgid",settings.getString("orgid", "") );

    socket.emit("joinparty", arrays);
    socket.on(RECEIVE_CRISIS, onCallback);
    socket.on("connect_error", onCallback);
    socket.on("connect", onCallback);
    socket.on("Object", onCallback);
    socket.on("connect_timeout", onCallback);
}

private Emitter.Listener onCallback = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e(TAG, args[0]+"");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the NSDictionary is equivalent to the JSONObject on Android?

No, it's not. NSDictionary is a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html), meaning that the actual implementation is hidden from you, the API user. In fact, the `Foundation` framework will choose the appropriate implementation at run time based on amount of data etc. The closest to it for Java is `Map<Object, Object>`

> Is sendEvent equivalent to send() or emit() on Android?

It is emit for Android. [from official documentation](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/#emitting-events)

> DO I need to send the JSON as an Object or an Array?

Try sending a `Map` instead. JSON is a different thing. If your server is expecting data in JSON format, than only send it.

> Finally, How to I get the log error?

You need to use [combination of emitter and manager](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io#emitter) for it.

Comment: Now I finally see an Error:  xhr poll error. I think It might be related to SSL certification since I had issue like this using Retrofit. I updated my question

Comment: For a different error,  kindly post an other question with the necessary details.

Comment: The initial issue wasn't fixed though